# How To downgrade Torch Version for Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, torch

I would like to downgrade the Torch version used in my Google Colab notebooks. How could I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run from your cell:

```
!pip install torch==version
```

Where version could be, for example, `1.3.0` (default is `1.4.0`). You may have to downgrade `torchvision` appropriately as well so you would go with:

```
!pip install torch==1.3.0 torchvision==0.4.1
```

On the other hand PyTorch provides backward compatibility between major versions so there should be no need for downgrading.

**Remember you have to restart your Google Colab for changes to take effect**

Comment: I tried restarting the runtime using the dropdown and then also tried restarting the kernel using multiple scripts online but none seemed to work and the version stayed the same. Can u please suggest me exactly which method to use to restart the colab for the changes to take effect??